# static parameters to be used as parameter list to choose from

Tags: java, variables, parameters, static

I have a class with two a final static parameters, which should be used as parameters:

```
class Abc {
    public final static String ASC = "ASC";
    public final static String DESC = "DESC";

    method(String parameter, LinkedList<type>) {
        //I also tried if(!(parameter == ASC)) or
        //if(!(sortMode.equals(ASC)))
        if(parameter != ASC || parameter != DESC) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if(parameter == ASC) {
            do this
        } else if(parameter == DESC) {
            do that
        }
    }
}
```

The class should be used as follows - here's a testMethod in JUnit3:

```
Abc sort2 = new Abc();
//... declaration and initializing list5

public void testCatchIllegalArgument() {
    boolean passed = false;
    try {
        sort2.method("abc", list5);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        passed = true;
    }
        assertEquals("... "
            + " failed.", true, passed);        
}
```

It actually does not catch the IllegalArgumentException - the boolean variable passed stays false after running the test.

What I basically intend to do is to have two parameters fixed in this class that can be selected in a method as parameters, but I do not want to save both of these in each object of this class.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: JUnit 3, wow, it is old.

Comment: `parameter != ASC || parameter != DESC` that should always be true because the parameter can either be ASC or DESC and will not be equal to the other - and here I used another keyword: don't compare strings using `==` but use `equals()` or in your case probably even `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Comment: `if(parameter != ASC || parameter != DESC) {` this will always be true

Comment: Btw, why don't you use enums instead of string constants?

Comment: Btw Why name your method `method`? Why not `assertTrue`? Why use a message of `"..." + "fail"`? Why use poor indentation? Why not show us `list5`? Why not use `equals()` for comparing Strings? Why have a condition that will always return true?

Comment: ah yes, I see, I need to add && and not ||...

I have never heard of enums before, but will check that - I'm still a learner, and we also use JUnit3, which is basically old, but the intention is to get into OOP and general stuff.

poor intendation... just wanted to shorten the code and not insert the full stuff. The rest works fine, just this IllegalArgumentExc just... but, issue solved when using &&

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Abc {
    public final static String ASC = "ASC";
    public final static String DESC = "DESC";

    public method(String parameter, LinkedList<type>) {
        if(!ASC.equalsIgnoreCase(parameter) && !DESC.equalsIgnoreCase(parameter)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if(ASC.equalsIgnoreCase(parameter)) {
            do this
        } else if(DESC.equalsIgnoreCase(parameter)) {
            do that
        }
    }
}

public void testCatchIllegalArgument() {
    boolean passed = false;
    try {
        sort2.method(Abc.ASC, list5);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        passed = true;
    }
        assertEquals("... "
            + " failed.", true, passed);        
}
```